# I have a 1983 ford f250, can i straight pipe it?

Tags: ford, carburetor

I have a 1983 ford f250, and I want to know if I straight pipe it, will it mess with my carburetor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Mess with your carburetor? No. Won't do anything to your carb. It'll give you a little more flow out the tailpipe, which may affect how much air can move through the system, but the carb should be able to compensate for it. If you are running regular exhaust manifolds or shorty headers, you probably won't see much gains in the power department. If you're running long tubes, then you might. If you are running long tube headers, you may need to rejet for the top end to ensure you have enough fuel when (and if) you go wide open throttle at higher speeds. Other than that, it shouldn't affect how the carb behaves.